# (KDE4) Plasma::TextEdit.nativeWidget()->setHtml() does not accept a colors

Tags: qtextedit, textedit, kde4, plasmoid

I have a plasmoid-application which utilises an objects of the `Plasma::TextEdit` class. And now I could to colorize a text in this objects. I had tried to do this:

```
m_text->nativeWidget()->setHtml("<font color=\"#777777\">some text</font><br/>other text");
```

with a couple of variants (like using the `span` tag with the `stile` attribute instead of the `font`, using the `red` color name instead the `#777777`), but result was the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "bug" was not in the programming: it turns out that there was need to restart the KDE.

Does anybody know why this happens? And what may I do to "flush" some cache or something else in order that the KDE picks a new version of my plasmoid up?